# How to edit the modified date of a folder/file?

Tags: c#, date, sharepoint, webdav

I am creating folders in SP using webdav with HttpWebRequest, MKCOL method.
And I upload files using WebClient.

For both uploaded files and created folders, how can I set their modified date?

I am looking for something similar to `Directory.SetLastWriteTime`, `File.SetLastWriteTime`

Answer (score 5):

You can use following code for that

```
//Change the file created time.
File.SetCreationTime(path, dtCreation);
//Change the file modified time.
File.SetLastWriteTime(path, dtModified);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 string path = @"c:\DirName";
 Directory.SetLastWriteTime(path, DateTime.Now);
 dt = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(path);
```